# BufferedReader to BigInteger variable

Tags: java, bufferedreader

So I have a very long text file and using Scanner to load it takes about half an hour so I'm trying to switch over to BufferedReader and this is the code I have right now

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader Br1 = null;
    BigInteger num = new BigInteger ("0");
    String Line = "";
    try {
        Br1 = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("text.txt"));
        System.out.println("Read line method");
        Line = Br1.readLine();
        while(Line != null) {
            num = num.add(new BigInteger(Line));
            System.out.println(Line);
            Line = Br1.readLine();
        }

        System.out.println("number " + num);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {System.out.println("error");}

}
```

To test it I made the text file
2
1
0
where all the numbers are on separate lines

I want it to give me a BigInteger 210 but instead it gives me 3, I tried messing around with different ways of adding to the BigInteger but I can't get it to work right. How should I do this?

Comment: `add` will add the numbers, so you are basically calculating 2+1+0=3. Why would you want to have 210?

Comment: What else do you expect from, num.add(new BigInteger(Line)); ?

Comment: Well I tried and, shiftLeft, and a couple other things but nothing worked

Comment: Why do you want to create a giant BiInteger like that in the first place. My guess is that there is a better way to do what you want to achieve. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BigInteger`, as the name suggests, is like an `Integer`. In `Integers`, `1+2+0` would be `3`, and not `120`. If that's what you want, do use `StringBuilder`, like

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("");
while(Line != null) {
    s.append(Line);
    Line = Br1.readLine();
}
```

If you want that as a `BigInteger`, do

```
BigInteger num = new BigInteger(s.toString());
```

Comment: But what if OP wants `BigInteger`?

Comment: @Kaushal28 considered.

Comment: Now this part of the code doesn't work 
 'num = new BigInteger(s);'
How should I change this?

Comment: @SamanthaClark : It should work. What's not working?

Comment: @SamanthaClark do `num = new BigInteger(s.toString())` The Constructor of `BigInteger` doesn't allow a `CharSequence`, only a `String`.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you very much for all your help

Comment: @SamanthaClark If it helped, you could select the answer by the buttons on the left.

Comment: I hit the green arrow, hope that selected your answer. Also it had the unexpected side affect of speeding up my program tremendously! :D

Comment: Oh, no wonder, I forgot to change it from loading the test example, I thought it was strange lol

Answer (score 0):

To get `210`, first append all characters to `String` and then convert to `BigInteger`, as following:

```
String number;
while(Line != null) {
    //num = num.add(new BigInteger(Line));
    number += Line;
    System.out.println(Line);
    Line = Br1.readLine();
}
num = new BigInteger(number);
```

Comment: doesn't make a much of a difference here, but you should prefer `StringBuilder` instead of `String` here, considering `Strings` are immutable, and add overhead to the program.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick :)

Comment: @SamanthaClark You are Welcome mate! please Consider @Shashwat comment and you can use `StringBuilder`. You can accept the answer if it helped :)